# How to drop unique rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am stuck with a seemingly easy problem: dropping unique rows in a pandas dataframe. Basically, the opposite of [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Let's say this is my data:

```
    A       B   C  
0   foo     0   A
1   foo     1   A
2   foo     1   B
3   bar     1   A
```

I would like to drop the rows when A, and B are unique, i.e. I would like to keep only the rows 1 and 2.

I tried the following:

```
# Load Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})

uniques = df[['A', 'B']].drop_duplicates()
duplicates = df[~df.index.isin(uniques.index)]
```

But I only get the row 2, as 0, 1, and 3 are in the uniques!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solutions for select all duplicated rows:

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with subset and parameter `keep=False` for select all duplicates:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)]
print (df)
     A  B  C
1  foo  1  A
2  foo  1  B
```

Solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].transform('size') > 1]
print (df)
     A  B  C
1  foo  1  A
2  foo  1  B
```

A bit modified solutions for select all unique rows:

```
#invert boolean mask by ~
df = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)]
print (df)
     A  B  C
0  foo  0  A
3  bar  1  A

df = df[df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].transform('size') == 1]
print (df)
     A  B  C
0  foo  0  A
3  bar  1  A
```

Comment: the first answer works. The second is resulting in two rows less (it might be because of `NaN`, my dataframe is very dirty and nothing can be assumed safely). For some reason, none of the inverting methods work.

Comment: So `df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)` works and `~df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)` not ?

Comment: And idea for deal with NaNs - i think `df = df[~df.fillna('').duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)]` should works. But I have no you real data, so hard answer.

Comment: neither `df[~df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)]` nor `df[df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].transform('size') == 1]` return anything in my original dataset (it does work in the example).

Comment: and `df[df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].transform('size') > 1]` returns two rows less in my original dataset...

Comment: Very hard answering, only idea is replace NaNs by some string which is no in `df` like `df = df[~df.fillna('$$$&&&???').duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)]` and then try :(

Comment: But in my opinion if data are bad then is necessary deeper analyse False positive rows, without data it is imposible

Comment: this is more than enough for my current needs, I am currently analyzing the database looking for weird stuff - I will post if I figure out what is happening. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution using `groupby`:

```
groupped = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})
uniques = groupped[groupped['count'] == 1]
duplicates = df[~df.index.isin(uniques.index)]
```

Duplicates now has the proper result:

```
    A       B   C
2   foo     1   B
3   bar     1   A
```

---

Also, my original attempt in the question can be fixed by simply adding `keep=False` in the `drop_duplicates` method:

```
# Load Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})

uniques = df[['A', 'B']].drop_duplicates(keep=False)
duplicates = df[~df.index.isin(uniques.index)]
```

---

Please @jezrael answer, I think it is safest(?), as I am using pandas indexes here.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'],keep=False)

df1 = pd.concat([df, df1])

df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

This technique is more suitable when you have two datasets `dfX` and `dfY` with millions of records. You may first concatenate `dfX` and `dfY` and follow the same steps.