# Removing unique rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas.DataFrame like this :

```
     time    num
 1    a ,A    3
 2    a ,B    3
 3    a ,C    1
 4    b ,A    4
 5    b ,A    4
 6    a ,B    3
 7    d ,B    2
```

I want to remove the rows where time is unique in the dataset. The result would be:

```
    time    num
 2    a ,B    3
 4    b ,A    4
 5    b ,A    4
 6    a ,B    3
```

Is there any way to do this without a loop???

Comment: What about `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: [How to drop unique rows in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888858/how-to-drop-unique-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

For example:

```
     A       B   C  
0   foo     0   A
1   foo     1   A
2   foo     1   B
3   bar     1   A

df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False)]
print (df)
     A  B  C
1  foo  1  A
2  foo  1  B
```

As subset, you would specify time.

Comment: not a pandas expert, and honest question: but how does that answer isn't a duplicate from the link you quoted (which would make the question a duplicate, not needing answering)

Comment: this is true. I'm new to Stack Overflow. How does one go about marking a question as duplicate?

Comment: this has already been done by power users. Honest mistake, you won't get burned for it. Next time comment like "possible duplicate of" or use "flag => duplicate".